# Context free grammar for these langauges?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar

I've been working on trying to generate context free grammars for different problems and currently I'm working on these but after trying over and over, I can't come up with ones for these:

1) the palindrome langauge $\{z \in \{0,1\}^* \mid z = z^R\}$ where $R$ is the reverse of $z$.

2) $\{0^x1^y0^z \mid x,y,z \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } (x=y \text{ or } y=z)\}$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Palindromes are easy: build them from the middle out. You can get all of them of even length with the productions $S\to\lambda\mid 0S0\mid 1S1$; you’ll have to work just a *little* harder to get the ones of odd length. (I use $\lambda$ for the empty word; many people use $\varepsilon$.)

Your second language is the union of two simpler languages:

$$L_1=\{0^x1^x0^y:x,y\in\Bbb N\}$$

and

$$L_2=\{0^x1^y0^y:x,y\in\Bbb N\}\;.$$

For $L_1$ you can start with $S\to AB$, then add productions so that $A$ produces strings of the form $0^x1^x$, and $B$ produces strings of zeroes. (The trick of building from the middle out will help you again here.) $L_2$ has a very similar grammar, and combining the grammars is straightforward: if their initial symbols are $S_1$ and $S_2$, start with $S\to S_1\mid S_2$.